# Angular 1 + typescript: Populate html with data retrieved from api calls all at the same time

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I am working on a messaging app in angular 1 with typescript that allows you to send any type of file. When the page loads I make api calls to retrieve the fileNames of the files already in the chat history.
Problem is, those api calls happen at different times so the html is populated with fileNames at different times causing this jumpy unclean look. How can I populate the html with data from the server at the same time?

```js
//Controller
export class MessageController {
  fileName: string;
  mediaId: string;

  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  protected init() {
    this.mediaId = "34567890"
    this.service.getFileName(this.mediaId)
      .then(data => {
        // interpolated in html as messageController.fileName
        this.fileName = data.fileName;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.$log.error(error);
      });
  }
}

// Directive
export class MessageDirective implements ng.IDirective {
    public restrict = 'E';
    public scope = true;
    public bindToController = {

    };
    public templateUrl = "someWhere;
    public controllerAs = 'MessageController';
    public controller = MessageController;

}

// Service
public getFileName(id: string): ng.IPromise<ContentItem> {
        var deferred: ng.IDeferred<ContentItem> = this.$q.defer();

        this.contentApiClient.get().one(id.toString()).get()
            .then((contentItem: ContentItem) => {
                deferred.resolve(contentItem);
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

```html
<div class="td-fsMessage">
  <p class="td-fsMessage-content-title">{{ messageController.fileName }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try getting data in the resolve method of this route. Then you could pass that data to controller. Which means, you can make sure that data is present when the controller itself is loaded

Comment: @Developer The data is retrieved from the controller (api calls happen when the controller is initialized), how can the data be present when the controller is loaded?

Comment: From angular route documentation: resolve - {Object.<string, Function>=} - An optional map of dependencies which should be injected into the controller. If any of these dependencies are promises, the router will wait for them all to be resolved or one to be rejected before the controller is instantiated. If all the promises are resolved successfully, the values of the resolved promises are injected and $routeChangeSuccess event is fired. If any of the promises are rejected the $routeChangeError event is fired. For easier access to the resolved dependencies from the template, the ...

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: In general, you should not make these http requests from the directives. The controller (of the page, not of the directive) should get the data, and then pass the date to the directives. And you're then free to use resolve, or $q.all() from the controller, to provide all the data at once to the template.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs guys ^^ .I ended up using a link function in the directive to call functions in the controller which then assign the data from api calls to the scope variables. This gives me the desired outcome, just now wondering if i can make it even better.